# Soft body not colliding with each other

Tags: physics, collision, soft-body

I am trying to make an animation using soft bodies, but the problem is that they are passing through each other. I have turned on Collision in the physics panel.
Thanks.
[Blend File](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51758)
[image: The Error]

Comment: it looks like your link doesn't work

Comment: I have updated it. Please check it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I just needed to check 'Faces' option in 'Soft Body Edges' settings.

Comment: a little late but you should mark this as the answer to your question!

Answer (score 0):

You also need to enable "Rigid body" for each of the objects

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried it but the object falls through the floor. Also, I have watched some tutorials and in that, they just enable soft body and collision and it works.

Comment: Have you given the Floor a Passive Dynamics?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Tried it just now. The same problem persists. I have attached the blend file with the question for reference.

Comment: Subdivide it a bit and it works, I think it must be just that

Comment: You mean I should subdivide it while applying rigid body or without rigid body? I have tried it both ways but the problem still persists.

Comment: In [this](https://youtu.be/4gYsxqNJyu8?t=439) link, he has applied only soft body and collision but it still works.

Comment: Select your object, go in Edit mode, select all and press W > Subdivide, same for the other one, it works, I guess the objects need to be a bit subdivided

Answer (score 0):

Select your object, go in *Edit* mode, select all and press <kbd>W</kbd> > *Subdivide*, same for the other one, it works, I guess the objects need to be a bit subdivided to interact properly with each others.